# Converting Lat, Long, Altitude, Pitch, Roll and Heading into Keyframed animation

Tags: python, scripting

I have a CSV file exported from a simulation program with Lattitude, Longitude, Altitude, Pitch, Roll, and Heading every 33ms, each line represents 33ms of the simulated result. What is the fastest way to convert it to Blender's XYZ, and Euler rotation to animate an empty with python?

Comment: There's a recent (long) YT tutorial by Erindale on using python and Geometry nodes with CSV data [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWwoWi_vPTg) which might be of use to you.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments to that video, there's also a free spreadsheet importer addon by Simon Broggi [here](https://github.com/simonbroggi/blender_spreadsheet_import) which you might find useful.